# How can I find an upper bound for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n+n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

My prof. asked to find an upper bound for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n+n}$.1.how can I find upper bound ?
2. Is there a closed form formula for $s_n=\frac{1}{2^1+1}+\frac{1}{2^2+2}+...+\frac{1}{2^n+n}$?
Can you hint me to find a sharp bound for it?

Comment: Here's one way: $\dfrac{1}{2^n+n}\le \dfrac{1}{2^n}=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^n$

Comment: If you need better upper bound than $1$ (as shown above) then you can for example use $I = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n+n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}\frac{1}{1  +\frac{n}{2^n}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\left[1 - \frac{n}{2^n} + \frac{n^2}{2^{2n}} - \frac{n^3}{2^{3n}} + \ldots\right]$ and since the series above is alternating you can easily estimate the error of cutting off the summation after $k$ terms.